# IBM Watson Translate apikey authorization failure with Postman

Tags: postman, ibm-watson

IBM Watson Translate is working with `curl`, but we can't get it to work with Postman. We have an `apikey` but I don't know where to put it in Postman. I looked through the `Authorization` tab and didn't see any options that accept an `apikey` (the options include `Basic Auth`, `Digest Auth`, etc.). I tried putting our `apikey`  in `Params` and in `Headers` but we always get back `401, Unauthorized`. Our `apikey` works with `curl`.

Comment: Since it's an IBM API, it might be worth trying their API Test and Monitor product http://ibm.biz/apitest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Postman, you can use Basic Auth with "apikey" as your Username and the apikey value shown on the Watson Language translator service as your password as shown in the image below.

[image]

Body will be raw JSON with the content-type set to "application/json"

```
{"text":["Hello"],"model_id":"en-es"}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! We also set a param to "version: 2018-05-01", and a header to "Content-Type: application/json", and we changed our single quotes to double quotes in our body (JSON requires double quotes, not single quotes).